# How to count the occurrence of different versions of a string in a column of a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe. [Click here to get the pic of the dataframe:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJehr.png)

In other words:

A male has been indicated by MALE/M/male/Male.

A female has been indicated by Female,F,Fem.

Positive responses are indicated by YES/yes/yeah.

Negative responses are indicated by no/NO/nope.

So,for the above dataframe, I would like to **count** in Python, the **total** number of males,**total** number of females,**total** number of positive responses and **total** number of negative responses. How can I do it ?

Comment: You can get a sample of your dataframe by using df.to_clipboard(), it'll help people get a hang of your data better than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `str[0]` for select first letter form each column, convert to [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html), compare and count number of `True`s by `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Gender':['Male', 'MALE', 'Female', 'F', 'M'],
                        'Response': ['yes', 'N', 'no', 'nope', 'NO']})
print (df)
   Gender Response
0    Male      yes
1    MALE        N
2  Female       no
3       F     nope
4       M       NO

count = len(df.index)
males = (df['Gender'].str[0].str.lower() == 'm').sum()
females = (df['Gender'].str[0].str.lower() == 'f').sum()

yes = (df['Response'].str[0].str.lower() == 'y').sum()
no = (df['Response'].str[0].str.lower() == 'n').sum()

print (count)
5
print (males)
3
print (females)
2
print (yes)
1
print (no)
4
```

Another solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and last rename `index` values by `dict`:

```
a = df['Gender'].str[0].str.lower().value_counts()
b = df['Response'].str[0].str.lower().value_counts()

s = pd.concat([a,b])
s.loc['count'] = len(df.index)
d = {'m':'male', 'f':'female', 'y':'yes', 'n':'no'}
s = s.rename(index=d)
print (s)
male      3
female    2
no        4
yes       1
count     5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the count of each value :

```
df.Gender.count_values()
```

Then add the value you want to group together